# Django : Import javascript inside a template doesn't work

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm facing a new problem with django. I'm developping a website (so I'm not in the production step) and I want to use javascript in my template.

When I write my script directly on my template and link it to a button the script works. But when I want to import it from a .js file it doesn't works anymore.

My static directory seems to work correctly, I can import css or even images from it.

Here is my files :

**base.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        {% load static %}

        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'webcalendar/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'webcalendar/css/style.css' %}">

        {% block script %}  {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>

        {% block content %}  {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

**fonction_test.html :** where the script is directly written in the template

```
{% extends 'webcalendar/base.html' %}

{% block script %}

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function printInConsole(){
                console.log("PRINTING...")
        }

    </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <button  onclick="printInConsole()" class="btn btn-warning">Print in console</button>

{% endblock %}
```

So the **previous one is working**.

But if I try to import the script from a .js file in the static folder of my app it doesn't works.

**calendar.js :**

```
function printInConsole(){
            console.log("PRINTING...")
    }
```

**new fonction_test.html :** where I try to import the script from the .js

```
{% extends 'webcalendar/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block script %}

    <script type="text/javascript" scr="{% static 'webcalendar/js/calendar.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <button  onclick="printInConsole()" class="btn btn-warning">Print in console</button>

{% endblock %}
```

**I get the following error :**

```
ReferenceError: printInConsole is not defined
```

I must have done something wrong, do you have any tips to solve this ?

Comment: Can you try with path like this : `<script src="path_to_your_static/static/webcalendar/js/calendar.js"></script>`. Then it seems to not work because you wrote : `scr` and not `src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, your issue comes from your syntax :

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="{% static 'webcalendar/js/calendar.js' %}"></script>
```

Please change `scr=""` by `src="`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'webcalendar/js/calendar.js' %}"></script>
```

If you're statics are well-defined, it should work.